# Programmatically build dynamic query with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to build a search from input received from a form.

```
router.get('/data', function(req, res) {
    var firstName=req.body.firstName,
    lastName=req.body.lastName,
    companyName=req.body.companyName,
    email=req.body.email;
});
```

I'd like to build a query up from these values, but if the field has no value, I obviously don't want to include it in the search (searching for "" would change the results)

I've tried a couple different things, like building a string to place in:

```
mongoose.model('customers').find({QUERY STRING WOULD GO HERE} ,function(err, data) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(data);
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work properly. I also tried "stacking" search queries like this:

```
if(firstName !="") {
    mongoose.model('customers').find({firstName: firstName})
}
```

and then executing the search like this:

```
mongoose.model('customers').exec(function(err, customer){
    console.log(customer);
});
```

But that causes 500 errors (and I'm not sure if there's any more info I can get from them).

Please help a Newbie dynamically build a mongoose search query :(

Comment: Instead of a query string, have you tried constructing a query object? (if you're new to javascript other languages call it "hash" or "map" or "array")

Comment: @slebetman You're absolutely right. I looked up how to create an object, but just wasn't doing it properly :(

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try creating `query` object, like:

```
//generate query object based on availability of value 
var query = {};
if( your_variable !== "" ) {
    query["some_key"] = your_variable;
}
if( your_second_variable !== "" ) {
    query["some_other_key"] = your_second_variable;
}
mongoose.model('customers').find(query, function(err, c) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: I did exactly this and it worked! I was trying to make an object wrong the whole time! Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Hi DemoUser,
If I want to put the 'in' checking how to use the above one, means I want check this {usernames: {$in:['x','y','z']}} . In this case what is first variable and second variable.

Comment: @RamBen - you can use: query["usernames"] = {$in:['x','y','z']}}

Answer (score 13):

For people using newer JavaScript (and especially on Node.js 7.6.0+ or Babel).

The best way I found for programmatically building queries (based on `if` clauses etc.) is using the Query and the alternative syntax.

```
let query = PersonModel().find();

if (isMale) {
    query.where('sex', 'male'); 
} else {
    query.where('sex', 'female');
}

query.where('alive', true);

// and then to run the query
const result = await query.exec();
```

Note the `async/await` usage here. It's working perfectly on Node.js 7.6.0+. If you don't want to use `async/await` you can just use Promises like so:

```
query.exec().then(result => {
    // result has your... results
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! My usecase is a lot simpler than that, but I appreciate it either way! I'm sure someone will get good use of it!

Comment: Before using `$where` make sure you consider these points,https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Answer (score 10):

To avoid checking each parameter independently you can loop through them.

```
var query = {};
for(var key in req.body){ //could also be req.query and req.params
  req.body[key] !== "" ? query[key] = req.body[key] : null;
}

mongoose.model('customers').find(query, function(err, customers){

})
```

Comment: This is pretty helpful, thanks! I've done this in a couple other places in my app and it's been pretty helpful!